# Azure DevOps Pipelines to run selected envirorment from codeway.yml file

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

i need some help on running selected envirorment from azure devops pipeline.
i used codeway.yml file which consisting of 3 env. like dev/qa/pro.
so when i run pipeline all the env are running one after other.

But my requirement is i want to run only selected env (other env should not run) with choice parameter like in jenkins
also needed "proceed to qa or pro" such a condition input needed.

could some help sample code for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable in the pipeline, and after that use this variable to execute the tasks stages that you want, previously consider that you need to have an starter point, here I use the stage info:

```
variables:
  isDevelop: true
  isQA: false
  isProd: false

 
- stage: Info
  displayName: 'Information for deploy'
  jobs:
    - whatever
      steps:

- stage: Dev
  displayName: 'Deploy to Dev'
  dependsOn: Info
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isDevelop'], true))
  jobs:
  - whatever


- stage: QA
  displayName: 'Deploy to QA'
  dependsOn: Info
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isQA'], true))
  jobs:
  - whatever


- stage: Prod
  displayName: 'Deploy to Prod'
  dependsOn: Info
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isProd'], true))
  jobs:
  - whatever
```

The variables can be calculated or alse you can get the value from the variables pipeline definition in azure, in the code below would be calculated using the sourcebranch, consider that is an example, and you need to adapt it to your project:

```
variables:
  isDevelop: $[eq(variables['sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')]
  isQA: $[eq(variables['sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/qa')]
  isProd: $[eq(variables['sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/prod')]
```

Comment: thanks javier for the quick response, i wanted the environments to be pop up to select like a choice parameters in this file. like when we run pipeline then it should ask us to select dev , qa , pro like choice parameters how we have it in jenkins same way. is there anyway to achieve like that also approval to proceed to qa and pro ... thank you